# Fatal exception: main cocos2Dx android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash, cocos2d-x

Hi I am having a problem running my cocos2Dx game on Android. Everything runs fine on iPhone. When I run the application it crashes straight away. I cannot work out what it is and have very little experience with java/android. Here is my logcat.

```
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/Trace(4004): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-13 21:20:05.322: W/dalvikvm(4004): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/lochlanna/parachuters/Parachuters;
09-13 21:20:05.322: W/dalvikvm(4004): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/lochlanna/parachuters/Parachuters;)
09-13 21:20:05.322: D/AndroidRuntime(4004): Shutting down VM
09-13 21:20:05.322: W/dalvikvm(4004): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b544300)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2090)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load game: findLibrary returned null
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     at com.lochlanna.parachuters.Parachuters.(Parachuters.java:51)
09-13 21:20:05.322: E/AndroidRuntime(4004):     ... 15 more
09-13 21:25:05.332: I/Process(4004): Sending signal. PID: 4004 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you build using build_native.sh ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a missing library file (.so file) in your libs folder.